# What is the suggested approach to allow user to export data on Android?

Tags: android, export

I am creating an app and I need to add the possibility to export the data stored in the app.
Is there any best practice to follow?

At the moment I create a file in `Context.cacheDir` and notify `DownloadManager` about it.
The file cannot be opened in the end, but I am wondering if there is a best practice to follow for this kind of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` for single-file exports. This will let the user decide where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) you should export the user's data.

If your export involves multiple files, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and create a sub-tree in which to place that content.

Comment: Hi @commonsware and thanks for the answer.
Using the approach you suggest, it is not needed to use the DownloadManager (or Media<whatever>) to notify the end of the export, right?

Comment: @Sixro: Correct. You get a `Uri` that you can use with `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()`. You write your content to the stream, close the stream, and tell the user "we're done!". FWIW, in the context of Room databases, I cover this approach in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-backup-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room).